# Is there a geometrical reason because we define a norm as a map from a space into $[0, +\infty[$ and not into $[0, +\infty]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

For convenience i replace a precise definition of a norm:

**Def:** Let **X** a vector space on a subfield $\mathbb{F}$ of $\mathbb{C}$,
a *norm* on **X** is a map $p:\mathbf{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+=[0, +\infty[$
such that:

1. *Subadditivity/Triangle inequality*: $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)\hspace{0.5cm} \forall x, y\in \mathbf{X}$
2. *Absolute homogeneity*:$p(\mathbb{s}x)= |\mathbb{s}|p(x)\hspace{0.5cm} \forall x\in \mathbf{X}\hspace{0.1cm} \forall  \mathbb{s}\in \mathbb{F}$
3. *Positive definiteness/positiveness/Point-separating*: if $p(x)=0 \text{, then } x=0$

So my question is: **Why we cannot admit for $\mathbf{+\infty}$ in the image of the norm?**

I have read something on the *norm extended* concept, and, if i understood, it's something usefull for example in quantum mechanics when we want introduce the rigged hilbert space to having only one math object that described the countinuos and discrete spectrum. But on this i don't know the details so maybe i'm wrong on something.

Regardless of that, i'm curious to know if there is some topological reason for this definition, because at first seems to me that in both of the case the *topology inducted by the norm* is a well-defined concept.

Comment: You can, but if you introduce infinity, things like $(a+b)-b = a+(b-b)$ start breaking down, and that's not fun.

Comment: I Am Not A Functional Analyst, but if $|v| = \infty$, then $|tv| = |0| = 0$ for $t = 0$ and $|tv| = |v| = \infty$ for $t = 1$. Since one basic purpose of a norm is to facilitate analysis via the triangle inequality, this discontinuity/lack of control on norm bounds looks ... vexing.

Comment: Often we want to normalize: $x/p(x)$. This is not possible if $p(x)$ is not an element of the field.

Comment: You have a very unusual concept of a norm. Usually one requires $p(\mathbb{s}x) =|\mathbb{s}|p(x)\hspace{0.5cm} \forall x\in \mathbf{X}\hspace{0.1cm} \forall  \mathbb{s}\in \mathbb{F}$. And you should not write $\mathbb R = [0,\infty[$.

Comment: @PaulFrost You're right, i made some typing errore. I think that i correct all of It now.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if $\|v\|=\infty$ then the line $\{tv\}$ becomes totally disconnected (in fact discrete), so scalar multiplication is no longer continuous.

Moreover, in general for an extended metric space, allowing values of infinity has the effect, topologically, of separating your space into a disjoint union of closed and open subsets on which the restriction of the metric is finite.

So when you study an extended metric space, you’re really looking at the finite components as separated pieces of the space.

In the special case of a norm, however, these “pieces” are all the same.  That is, the space becomes an uncountable disjoint union of closed/open isometric copies of the linear subspace on which the norm is finite. These are in fact the connected components of your space, and each is a translation of the finite-normed subspace by an infinite-normed vector.

So you are left wondering, why not just study that subspace? (You will observe that many times we do exactly that, e.g., you could define $L^p$ norm to allow infinite values and the subspace on which it is finite, where all the action happens, would be the same space that we actually study today.)

Answer (score 1):

You can define infinite norms if you want but they're not useful for much. As commenters have said, we want norms around to do analysis which involves a lot of estimating and bounding norms via the triangle inequality and similar, and infinite norms spoil our ability to do this.

Given a norm-that-is-allowed-to-be-infinite you can also check that the subset of $V$ on which the norm is finite is a subspace and so a normed vector space in the usual sense, and interesting analysis is only really possible on this subspace anyway, so might as well restrict attention to it.